# Why I cant create a new connection in SQL in VS code

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

When i am trying to make a new connection in VS Code, this error message popped-off

[image: The Error]

One another thing, Could someone just tell me what are the needed extensions to work with mysql in VS-code.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. If you are trying to connect to MySQL, then using methods to connect to SQL Server isn't going to work.

Comment: sorry i mean sql

Comment: SQL is a language; you don't connect to it.

Comment: okay then how can i connect to MYSQL  server

Answer (score 0):

It's because mysql default root user cant login with password and is set to auth_socket. To change this behavior you should connect to mysql if you on linux with this command: `sudo mysql -u root` and run this command to enable password login: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`